# Get IP Address of VMWare VM Hosted in OSX with Bash

Tags: bash, vmware

I'm running a VM from the command line with no GUI using VMWare Fusion.  Now I want to get the IP address of this VM.  How does one do this?  Here's the command I use to start the VM:

```
vmrun start "$vmFile" nogui
```

where `$vmFile` is the path to my VM image.

What commands can I run in the Bash terminal on OSX to get this info?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/373192/how-do-i-find-the-ip-address-of-a-virtual-machine-using-vmware-fusion

Comment: Question is more _suited_ in superuser.com, than here. Ask the mods to move it there.